# Are Learning Resources topics with specific resources as examples appropriate for Documentation?

Tags: discussion, documentation

I discovered the Documentation tab late last week, and I added to an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/common-lisp/534/getting-started-with-common-lisp/27861/common-lisp-learning-resources#t=201702161207181388469) to the [Common Lisp Getting Started](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/common-lisp/534/getting-started-with-common-lisp) topic that just contains learning resources.

In this case, "resources" means books, community websites, standards, etc. Blog posts are not deep enough or permanent enough to get one really started on a technology.

I originally added the example after seeing this done for another topic. Now my "example" has been upvoted to be on par with the other getting started example.

This was before I started doing some reading about documentation, and I'm getting the impression that:

- Examples were intended to be *actual examples*. So my "learning resources" example is probably wrong.
- The SO team doesn't seem very sure what documentation is going to evolve into yet.

The rules are different and a little vague for Documentation. Now my question is whether this is a place where opinion should matter. If there's a "Learning Resources" topic, and people posted specific resources as examples, upvoting the ones that are relevant, and downvoting the ones that are not, is that in line with the goal of Documentation?

Because sometimes the answer is "read the manual" but it may be hard to tell which manual to read, or which manual to read next, or which manual is good, or *why* the manual is good.

So is this an acceptable use of Documentation? Or do the same rules for questions on SO count?

Comment: While I like a "good beginner resources" section, I'm not sure if Documentation is currently the right place for it. Too easy for people to plug their own work or their own favorites. Maybe Documentation should have a "beginner resources" section that only tag-badge holders can edit.

Comment: Shouldn't that be in the "Remarks" section? It seems like a "We've got this documentation, but there're these other awesome places too" thing than an example of how to get started.

Comment: @S.L.Barth: "*Too easy for people to plug their own work or their own favorites.*" If it's a good resource, isn't that a good thing? And if it's not a good resource, it should be removed. And if we can trust people to curate "documentation" at all, why can't we trust them to curate a list of links?

Comment: @NicolBolas Right at the moment, I don't have much faith in the curation on Documentation. I'm willing to reconsider if quality control improves. A list of resources, _properly maintained_, could be very useful.

Comment: @S.L.Barth: My overall point is that the question of who should be allowed to edit it and who shouldn't is just as applicable to the rest of Docs.SO as it is to an example/remarks/whatever that has a list of resources. Currently, Docs.SO operates under the belief that anyone can edit. If that can produce good documentation, then it can produce a good list of resources. And if it can't produce a good list of resources, then it can't produce good documentation.

Answer (score 4):

On the one hand, having a list of resources is good for something that calls itself "documentation". On the other hand, Docs.SO isn't really good at making documentation. And Docs.SO is trying to be example-focused, so a list of links is not really in that domain.

If you're going to do it, it probably shouldn't be an Example in a general topic. After all, what would it mean to upvote that example relative to examples with actual code? Is a list of references "better" in some objective way than something else?

But the Remarks section is too far down the page for anyone to actually read. And the Syntax section doesn't really fit.

It seems to me that, if you're going to do it, it should be its own topic with a single example that has the relevant list of links. Indeed, there could be multiple categories of links: tutorials, general documentation, etc, with each category being a separate example.

Then again, such a set of examples would be way too easy to use to gain lots of rep.

Comment: More people would reach Remarks if that Getting Started page were cleaned up. Four hello worlds plus lambas and sums looks like overkill to me.